# How to load Text from TextField, checkbox, RadioButton, ComboBox to one Big Text Field

Tags: java, checkbox

I'm writing a simple program for recruiting employees.

I have few questions with `JtextField`, few checkboxes with text, a RadioButton with text and a Combobox.

I need the data entered in the text windows, checkbox, drop-down list to be thrown into the large window on the right.
At the moment there are only data from the text windows, but not from the top just in the middle of the field.

```
package appka;
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.Checkbox;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class CzwartaApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Klasy obiektow
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Czwarta Aplikacja");

        JButton btnSubmit = new JButton("Wypisz");
        JButton btnExit = new JButton("Wyjdz");

        JLabel lbl1 = new JLabel("imię");
        JLabel lbl2 = new JLabel("nazwisko");
        JLabel lbl3 = new JLabel("stanowisko");
        JLabel lbl4 = new JLabel("E-mail");
        JLabel lbl5 = new JLabel("");
        JLabel lbl6 = new JLabel("Jakie znasz języki programowania?");
        JLabel lbl7 = new JLabel("Wybierz poziom języka angielskiego?");
        JLabel lbl8 = new JLabel("Wybierz kurs programowania?");
        JLabel lbl9 = new JLabel("Dane Kontaktowe");

        JTextField tf1 = new JTextField();
        JTextField tf2 = new JTextField();
        JTextField tf3 = new JTextField();
        JTextField tf4 = new JTextField();
        JTextField tf5 = new JTextField();

        Checkbox checkbox1 = new Checkbox("Java");
        Checkbox checkbox2 = new Checkbox("Python");
        Checkbox checkbox3 = new Checkbox("Inne");

        JRadioButton btn1 = new JRadioButton();
        btn1.setText("podstawowy");
        JRadioButton btn2 = new JRadioButton();
        btn2.setText("średnio-zaawansowany");
        JRadioButton btn3 = new JRadioButton();
        btn3.setText("zaawansowany");
        ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup ();
        group.add(btn1); group.add(btn2); group.add(btn3);

        JComboBox kurs = new JComboBox();
        kurs.addItem("FrontEnd Developer");
        kurs.addItem("BackEnd Developer");

        // Pozycjonowanie
        lbl1.setBounds(20, 20, 100, 20);
        tf1.setBounds(20, 70, 100, 20);
        lbl2.setBounds(20, 120, 100, 20);
        tf2.setBounds(20, 170, 100, 20);
        lbl3.setBounds(20, 220, 100, 20);
        tf3.setBounds(20, 270, 100, 20);
        lbl4.setBounds(20, 320, 100, 20);
        tf4.setBounds(20, 370, 100, 20);
        tf5.setBounds(500, 20, 250, 300);
        lbl5.setBounds(20, 420, 300, 20);
        lbl6.setBounds(200, 20, 250, 20);
        lbl7.setBounds(200, 220, 250, 20);
        lbl8.setBounds(200, 350, 250, 20);
        lbl9.setBounds(500, 50, 200, 20);
        btnSubmit.setBounds(20, 470, 100, 20);
        btnExit.setBounds(220, 470, 100, 20);
        checkbox1.setBounds(200, 70, 250, 20);
        checkbox2.setBounds(200, 120, 250, 20);
        checkbox3.setBounds(200, 170, 250, 20);
        btn1.setBounds(200, 250, 250, 20);
        btn2.setBounds(200, 280, 250, 20);
        btn3.setBounds(200, 310, 250, 20);
        kurs.setBounds(200, 380, 250, 20);


        // Obsluga zdarzen
        btnSubmit.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

                String imie = tf1.getText();
                String nazwisko = tf2.getText();
                String stanowisko = tf3.getText();
                String email = tf4.getText();

                tf5.setText(imie+" "+nazwisko+" "+stanowisko+" "+email);

            }

        });
        btnExit.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        // Dodanie do okna
        frame.add(btnSubmit); frame.add(btnExit);
        frame.add(tf1); frame.add(tf2); frame.add(tf3);frame.add(tf4);frame.add(tf5);
        frame.add(lbl1); frame.add(lbl2); frame.add(lbl3); frame.add(lbl4);frame.add(lbl5);
        frame.add(lbl6);frame.add(lbl7);frame.add(lbl8);frame.add(lbl9);
        frame.add(checkbox1); frame.add(checkbox2); frame.add(checkbox3);
        frame.add(btn1); frame.add(btn2); frame.add(btn3);
        frame.getContentPane().add(kurs);
        frame.setSize(800, 600);
        frame.setLayout(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the corrected code.

```
import java.awt.Checkbox;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class CzwartaApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Klasy obiektow
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Czwarta Aplikacja");

        JButton btnSubmit = new JButton("Wypisz");
        JButton btnExit = new JButton("Wyjdz");

        JLabel lbl1 = new JLabel("imie");
        JLabel lbl2 = new JLabel("nazwisko");
        JLabel lbl3 = new JLabel("stanowisko");
        JLabel lbl4 = new JLabel("E-mail");
        JLabel lbl5 = new JLabel("");
        JLabel lbl6 = new JLabel("Jakie znasz jezyki programowania?");
        JLabel lbl7 = new JLabel("Wybierz poziom jezyka angielskiego?");
        JLabel lbl8 = new JLabel("Wybierz kurs programowania?");
        JLabel lbl9 = new JLabel("Dane Kontaktowe");

        final JTextField tf1 = new JTextField();
        final JTextField tf2 = new JTextField();
        final JTextField tf3 = new JTextField();
        final JTextField tf4 = new JTextField();
        final JTextArea tf5 = new JTextArea();

        final Checkbox checkbox1 = new Checkbox("Java");
        final Checkbox checkbox2 = new Checkbox("Python");
        final Checkbox checkbox3 = new Checkbox("Inne");

        JRadioButton btn1 = new JRadioButton();
        btn1.setText("podstawowy");
        JRadioButton btn2 = new JRadioButton();
        btn2.setText("srednio-zaawansowany");
        JRadioButton btn3 = new JRadioButton();
        btn3.setText("zaawansowany");
        ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
        group.add(btn1);
        group.add(btn2);
        group.add(btn3);

        final JComboBox kurs = new JComboBox();
        kurs.addItem("FrontEnd Developer");
        kurs.addItem("BackEnd Developer");

        // Pozycjonowanie
        lbl1.setBounds(20, 20, 100, 20);
        tf1.setBounds(20, 70, 100, 20);
        lbl2.setBounds(20, 120, 100, 20);
        tf2.setBounds(20, 170, 100, 20);
        lbl3.setBounds(20, 220, 100, 20);
        tf3.setBounds(20, 270, 100, 20);
        lbl4.setBounds(20, 320, 100, 20);
        tf4.setBounds(20, 370, 100, 20);
        tf5.setBounds(500, 20, 250, 300);
        lbl5.setBounds(20, 420, 300, 20);
        lbl6.setBounds(200, 20, 250, 20);
        lbl7.setBounds(200, 220, 250, 20);
        lbl8.setBounds(200, 350, 250, 20);
        lbl9.setBounds(500, 50, 200, 20);
        btnSubmit.setBounds(20, 470, 100, 20);
        btnExit.setBounds(220, 470, 100, 20);
        checkbox1.setBounds(200, 70, 250, 20);
        checkbox2.setBounds(200, 120, 250, 20);
        checkbox3.setBounds(200, 170, 250, 20);
        btn1.setBounds(200, 250, 250, 20);
        btn2.setBounds(200, 280, 250, 20);
        btn3.setBounds(200, 310, 250, 20);
        kurs.setBounds(200, 380, 250, 20);

        // Obsluga zdarzen
        btnSubmit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                String imie = tf1.getText();
                String nazwisko = tf2.getText();
                String stanowisko = tf3.getText();
                String email = tf4.getText();

                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                buffer.append( "imie : ").append( imie ).append("\n");
                buffer.append( "nazwisko : ").append( nazwisko ).append("\n");
                buffer.append( "stanowisko : ").append( stanowisko ).append("\n");
                buffer.append( "E-mail : ").append( email ).append("\n");
                buffer.append( "Jakie znasz jezyki programowania? : ");
                if( checkbox1.getState() ) {
                    buffer.append( checkbox1.getLabel() ).append(",");
                }
                if( checkbox2.getState() ) {
                    buffer.append( checkbox2.getLabel() ).append(",");
                }
                if( checkbox3.getState() ) {
                    buffer.append( checkbox3.getLabel() );
                }
                buffer.append("\n");

                buffer.append( "Wybierz kurs programowania? ").append( kurs.getSelectedItem().toString() ).append("\n");



                tf5.setText(buffer.toString());

            }

        });
        btnExit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        // Dodanie do okna
        frame.add(btnSubmit);
        frame.add(btnExit);
        frame.add(tf1);
        frame.add(tf2);
        frame.add(tf3);
        frame.add(tf4);
        frame.add(tf5);
        frame.add(lbl1);
        frame.add(lbl2);
        frame.add(lbl3);
        frame.add(lbl4);
        frame.add(lbl5);
        frame.add(lbl6);
        frame.add(lbl7);
        frame.add(lbl8);
        frame.add(lbl9);
        frame.add(checkbox1);
        frame.add(checkbox2);
        frame.add(checkbox3);
        frame.add(btn1);
        frame.add(btn2);
        frame.add(btn3);
        frame.getContentPane().add(kurs);
        frame.setSize(800, 600);
        frame.setLayout(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```